Access the existing schemas in pg using django
I am trying to access the existing schemas in the postgres database.But I can't.
There are several schemas in my pg db.Those schemas were created for the .net apis.Now I want to add a table in those schemas via django migration.
Is it possible to do that?

Unless something has changed recently Django does not have schema support per this long standing issue Schema support. This is one of the reasons I don't use migrations, instead I use Sqitch.

Ok I'll give it a try.
